# Crosstab de dos columnas en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tengo en PostgreSQL una tabla con este formato

| Anilla | Código |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 123 |
| A1 | 123 |
| A1 | 122 |
| A2 | 321 |
| A2 | 321 |
| A3 | 654 |
| A3 | 123 |

En esta tabla, las combinaciones de `Anilla` y `Código` deben ser siempre las mismas. Es decir, a cada anilla siempre le debe corresponder el mismo código, independientemente del número de veces que se repita esa anilla. Necesito una consulta (entiendo que es un `crosstab`) que me devuelva aquellas anillas que tienen más de un código asignado (he comprobado que ninguna tiene más de dos). Es decir, algo así

| Anilla | Código1 | Código2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 123 | 122 |
| A3 | 654 | 123 |

Supongo que no es una consulta complicada y he revisado los hilos de crosstab en StackOverflow, pero no consigo aclararme. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo esta forma:

```
SELECT anilla,array_agg(distinct codigo)
  FROM anillas
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT codigo)>1;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE anillas(
  id_anilla serial PRIMARY KEY,
  anilla varchar(7),
  codigo int
  );
INSERT INTO anillas (anilla, codigo) VALUES
  ('A1',123),('A1',123),('A1',122),
  ('A2',321),('A2',321),
  ('A3',654),('A3',123);
```

Obtendrías

```
anilla  array_agg
A1  {122,123}
A3  {123,654}
```

Te dejo el dbfiddle.uk en [PostgreSQL 14.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=faa6134c79b6ab36a7d6cf6b54969b76) y [MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5523ac0be1de7ad445150bdbe824976).

Para que puedas explotar ese resultado, puedes hacer esta otra consulta que no te agrupa los resultados:

```
SELECT DISTINCT anilla,codigo
  FROM anillas
  WHERE anilla IN (
    SELECT anilla
      FROM anillas
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT codigo)>1  
  )
  ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Mostrándotelos así:

```
anilla  codigo
A1  122
A1  123
A3  123
A3  654
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Esta solución me gusta, porque no presupune un número determinado de elementos del array. Sin embargo, aunque no lo necesito en este caso, entiendo que, precisamente, ese array dificulta una teórica automatización de acciones posteriores, ¿no?

Comment: Efectivamente, si hubiera más de dos, te los mostraría igualmente... Para acciones posteriores puedes hacer otra consulta que no agrupe, por ejemplo. Te amplío la respuesta